# Treat NSLayoutConstraint constant as multiplier?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have three horizontally aligned `UIView`s within a container `UIView`. These three views should span the entire width of the above `UIImageView`. The problem, however, is that sometimes only one or two of the child views should be shown.

I set up my view hierarchy like so:

[image]

Since the child views are set to be equal to the width of the first child (which will always be shown), I simply set the width of the first child to be a fraction of the `UIImageView` width. So if three child views should be shown, the first child view would have a multiplier of 1/3 the width of the `UIImageView`. If two child views should be shown, the multiplier would be 1/2. If just one, the multiplier would be 1.

This seemed like a perfect solution, however the multiplier property is read only. My first attempt to solve this was by creating three different `NSLayoutConstraint`s attached to the first child view, all with a different multiplier with 2/3 of them turned off. Then, on runtime, I would enable the appropriate constant with the appropriate multiplier based off of the number of views I wanted to show.

This resulted in a lot of ugly errors, and so did my second solution:

```
var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: color1, attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1/2, constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(constraint)
```

Where I would add a new constraint to the view based on the multiplier I wanted. This, of course, resulted in an error:

> When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled.

**My question**, therefore, is if I can treat the `constant` property like the `multiplier` property. My fear with doing this, however, is that if I set the `constant` for the width of the first child view, it would not update its width when the phone rotates.

Is there a better solution for all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, In your question your were using IB but you seemed to suggest there may be a different number of views each time you moved to the view controller which is why I decided to create the `NSLayoutConstraint`s programatically.

Secondly, my solution is fine provided you didn't intend to change the number of views whilst you were on the view controller. If you did, then this needs a bit more work.

In your view controller:

```
var viewWidthConstraints : [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let numberOfViews = 3
    var previousView: UIView = self.view

    for i in 0..<numberOfImages {
        let myView = UIView()
        myView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(CGFloat(i) * (1/CGFloat(numberOfImages)) + 0.1)
        self.view.addSubview(myView)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]|",
                                options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing,
                                metrics: nil,
                                views: ["view" : myView])

        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, 
                                attribute: .Width, 
                                relatedBy: .Equal, 
                                toItem: nil, 
                                attribute: .NotAnAttribute, 
                                multiplier: 1.0, 
                                constant: self.view.frame.width / CGFloat(numberOfImages))

        let attribute: NSLayoutAttribute = (i == 0) ? .Left : .Right
        let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView,
            attribute: .Left,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: previousView,
            attribute: attribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0)

        self.view.addConstraints(heightConstraint)
        self.view.addConstraint(leftConstraint)
        myView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

        viewWidthConstraints.append(widthConstraint)

        previousView = myView
    }
}

func updateWidthConstraints() {
    if viewWidthConstraints.count > 0 {
        let width = self.view.frame.width / CGFloat(viewWidthConstraints.count)

        for constraint in viewWidthConstraints {
            constraint.constant = width
        }
    }
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    updateWidthConstraints()
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` you add the `UIView`s to the view and set up their constraints. The vertical constraint you could change to make the `UIView`s appear underneath your `UIImageView`. And change `numberOfViews` to increase or decrease the number of views.

Then in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` you update the width of each view using their width constraint. This will make sure, if the device is rotated, each view takes up the correct proportion of the screen.

This is what is looked like with horizontal orientation.

[image]

And vertical orientation.

[image]

Comment: Wow, sorry for the late response. This works well, however I can't seem to put the views in a container view that doesn't span the entire screen. By this I mean that if I set `previousView` to a custom view that has a left and right constraint to its parent of 20px, the following happens: http://i.imgur.com/rV8ubou.png